# Assign Custom Function on Cancel Button Angular X-editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Is this possible? I have a code that looks like this:

`<div class="popover-wrapper">
    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" ng-if="activity.type === 'continuous'" ng-style=" { 'border': 'none', 'color': activity.timer.color.icon, 'cursor': 'pointer'}" editable-select="manualTimer.status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in manualTimerStatuses" onaftersave="timerSet()"></a>
 </div>`

The popover shows up with two buttons. The submit one changes the model, `manualTimer.status`. However, I am wondering if it is possible to assign a custom function to execute when the cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow angular-xeditable document in [here](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#ref-element)

Try to add `oncancel` attribute with your custom function. It will be trigger when you click **Cancel** button.

```
<div class="popover-wrapper">
    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" oncancel="yourfunction" ng-if="activity.type === 'continuous'" ng-style=" { 'border': 'none', 'color': activity.timer.color.icon, 'cursor': 'pointer'}" editable-select="manualTimer.status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in manualTimerStatuses" onaftersave="timerSet()" ></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Much appreciated!